# Validation on Custom Angular Material Form Field

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to make a wrapper component for a color picker using `ngx-color-picker` and Angular Materials `FormField`. I configured it as `required` but it's outline doesn't turn red when invalid like the other form fields... How can I achieve this behavior on my custom form field?

**color-picker.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, forwardRef } from '@angular/core'
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms'

// inspiration:
// https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html

export const requiredValidator = (c: FormControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    return
    c.value === '' ||
    c.value === null ||
    c.value === undefined ||
    c.value.length === 0
        ? {
              required: {
                  valid: false,
              },
          }
        : null
}

@Component({
    selector: 'nda-color-picker',
    templateUrl: './color-picker.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./color-picker.component.scss'],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
            useExisting: forwardRef(() => ColorPickerComponent),
            multi: true,
        },
    ],
})
export class ColorPickerComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, Validator {
    @Input() label: string
    _color: string

    get color() {
        return this._color
    }
    set color(value: string) {
        this._color = value
        this.propagateChange(this._color)
    }

    constructor() {}

    writeValue(value: any) {
        if (value !== undefined) {
            this.color = value
        }
    }

    propagateChange = (_: any) => {}

    registerOnChange(fn) {
        this.propagateChange = fn
    }

    registerOnTouched() {}

    validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
        return requiredValidator(control as FormControl)
    }
}
```

**color-picker.component.html**

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" [floatLabel]="'always'">
    <mat-label>{{ label }}</mat-label>
    <input
        matTooltip="{{ color }}"
        cpOKButton="true"
        cpCancelButton="true"
        [required]="required"
        matInput
        [ngStyle]="{ color: color, background: color }"
        [colorPicker]="color"
        (colorPickerChange)="color = $event"
    />
</mat-form-field>
```

**form-component.html**

```
<form
    [formGroup]="transportForm"
    autocomplete="off"
    (ngSubmit)="handleSubmit()"
>A
    <div mat-dialog-content>
        <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutGap="1rem">
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>Icon</mat-label>
                <input
                    matInput
                    placeholder="Icon"
                    formControlName="icon"
                    required
                />
            </mat-form-field>
            <nda-color-picker
                label="Badge Color Code"
                formControlName="badgeColorCode"
                required
            ></nda-color-picker>
            <nda-color-picker
                label="Text Color Code"
                formControlName="textColorCode"
                required
            ></nda-color-picker>
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>Badge Type</mat-label>
                <input
                    matInput
                    placeholder="Badge Type"
                    formControlName="badgeType"
                />
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- dialog actions -->
    <div mat-dialog-actions fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
        <div>
            <button
                type="button"
                *ngIf="data && data.code"
                color="warn"
                mat-flat-button
                (click)="handleDelete()"
            >
                DELETE
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-container">
            <button type="reset" mat-stroked-button (click)="handleCancel()">
                CANCEL
            </button>
            <button
                mat-flat-button
                color="accent"
                [disabled]="transportForm.pristine"
            >
                SAVE
            </button>
        </div>
        <div
            *ngIf="!transportForm.valid"
            class="mat-small dialog-error-message"
        >
            * Fill out all required fields
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

------ UPDATE ------

I updated the `color-picker.component` with a validator function and class implementing Validator interface. The validator function is actually called and works as expected. But the form field isn't marked as invalid as reactive form fields normally are (css class `.ng-invalid`).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54645878/is-it-possible-to-crate-a-validator-for-a-custom-component-not-for-a-formcontro/54648891#54648891

Comment: @Eliseo: I tried implementing NG_VALIDATORS like suggested in the link. But unfortunately it does not change anything...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ReactiveFormsModule` custom classes to set styles for different statuses :

```
.ng-invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

You can find more documentation about `ReactiveFormsModule` css classes in [angular.io...css-classes](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#control-status-css-classes).

Comment: The class `.ng-invalid` is not added to `<nda-color-picker>` like all the other inputs. So the problem must be, that `<nda-color-picker>` isn't validated at all.

Comment: I used this example https://alligator.io/angular/custom-form-control/ and added validation to make this https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-55165510 . It's working.

Comment: ibenjelloun, there a bug in your code, see my answer

Comment: Sorry but you're talking about alligator.io's code and it does not give additional value to the answer. @olefrank if you're still stuck with this make a stackblitz with your issue and I'll give it a look when I have time.

Answer (score 0):

ibenjelloun, there a bug in your code. Replace your function get value() to return null if ratting equals 0 else if select an start and deselect don't give you error

```
get value(): number {
    let ratting= this.stars.reduce((total, starred) => {
      return total + (starred ? 1 : 0);
    }, 0);
    return ratting?ratting:null;
  }
```

Olefrank if you want that the control was who give the error add providers and create function validate, see [the ibenjelloun forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-55165510-c2486t?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)